# How delimit blocks in GZIP file?

Tags: c, gzip

I am writing for learning purpose a C program that uncompress GZIP files.

According to the GZIP [spec](http://www.gzip.org/zlib/rfc-gzip.html)

> A gzip file consists of a series of "members" (compressed data sets).
>   The format of each member is specified in the following section. The
>   members simply appear one after another in the file, with no
>   additional information before, between, or after them.

and one member is made of a header (maybe with optional fields depending on some flags value), some compressed blocks (using deflate algorithm) and finally a CRC32 and the size of the original uncompressed file.

I have two questions:

1. How do I delimit members? In practice, are there really multiple members in one gzip file? It seems that one member corresponds to one file (filename header for example)
2. How do I delimit the last block from the trailer (CRC + SIZE)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not common, but you will sometimes see concatenated gzip streams in a single file.  gzip considers that to be a single stream of data, not multiple "files", so the file names are ignored.

If by "How delimit the last block" you mean the last deflate block, then the last deflate block simply has a bit in its header that marks it as the last block.  The last deflate block is followed by the crc and uncompressed length (modulo 2^32).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and since I read your name somewhere in the "specs" ;-) I am asking an other question here: I didn't investigate a lot yet the deflate stream compression, but how delimit these blocks ? I just read that each block as a header as you said with a last block bit but I can't see a "size" information. How do I know when I am reading a new header ?

Comment: Deflate blocks do not have a size prefix.  Instead they are self-terminating with an end code.  When you get to the end code, you look for a new block.  Or you process a trailer if the last block bit was set at the beginning of that block.

Comment: Thanks again. Can you just confirm that this end code value is 256 ?

Comment: The end code _value_ is 256, but know that that is not the end _code_.  The end code is a Huffman code whose length and bits are determined either by the dynamic code header of that block, or as the end code for static codes.

Comment: I am getting troubles to get my fixed block decoding working. I think the issue comes from bits order interpretation. In the spec it is said that Huffman codes are ordered in MSB while all other elements are ordered in LSB. is it true for the 2 bits of the type in the block header and for extra bits of length and distance (the spec says no) ? So what are these other data elements ?

Comment: You should look at contrib/puff/puff.c in the zlib distribution for a simple inflator that is intended to unambiguously define the deflate format by virtue of being a readable decoder.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but I coming back on my GZip app, and I have troubles with the CRC and uncompressed length. The issue is that these information doesn't appear directly after the last decoded block, I have some 0 (7 in the example I am working with) between the 2. How can I explain that ?

Comment: Either the gzip data is not valid, or you are not identifying the end of the last block properly.  Use gzip to see if the gzip data is valid.

Comment: Thanks for your help again. I just downloaded gzip source file to check where I am wrong (the archive is correct)

Comment: After deep investigations, I am still facing issue with my fixed encoded file. To have my decoder working, I have to align on a byte boundary at the end of the last block and before reading the crc32 and the original file size. Is it or not conform to the spec ?

Comment: Ah, I think I now understand "I have some 0 (7 in the example I am working with) between the 2" to mean you have up to 7 zero _bits_ between the end of the last block and the CRC.  I thought you meant zero _bytes_.  Yes, you go to the next byte boundary (unless you happen to already be at a byte boundary) to get the CRC.  The deflate format is a sequence of bytes.  From the deflate spec: "The specification specifies a method for representing a sequence of bytes as a (usually shorter) sequence of bits, and a method for packing the latter bit sequence into bytes."

Comment: Yes you are right, I have up to 7 zero bits between the last block and the CRC. And I didn't catch it from me spec, shame on me ! This time I am really ok with the GZip and deflate formats, many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> How do I delimit members?

Members aren't delimited. There's no separation between them, which is why you can `cat` gzipped files together in the same way you would non-gzipped files. However, once you reach the end of one member, you can look for the ID1 & ID2 values that indicate the start of the next member. From the spec:

> These have the fixed values ID1 = 31 (0x1f, \037), ID2 = 139 (0x8b, \213), to identify the file as being in gzip format.

This lets you tell the start of another member apart from garbage at the end of the file.

If you're looking to jump to a specific member in a file without reading all the others, you could use pre-computed indexes like a [CDX file provides](https://iipc.github.io/warc-specifications/specifications/cdx-format/cdx-2015/).

> In practice, are there really multiple members in one gzip file?

It's pretty common for gzipped [WARC files](http://bibnum.bnf.fr/warc/WARC_ISO_28500_version1_latestdraft.pdf) (used to archive websites). Each record is a separate member to make seeking easier. However, the format doesn't rely upon this feature.